# RequestFormLimitsAttribute on action not working with global AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

A week ago and I hit a error when a page started giving a giving generic 400 error. Turns out this is because there were too many form fields being sent to the server during a POST. For reasons that are not important, this was a page meant to allow editing multiple addresses all at once when dealing with a large apartment/condo building. I had 4 form fields per unit, plus some extras, so once a building had more than approx 250+ units, it hit the limit (1024). I tried applying `RequestFormLimitsAttribute` to the action handling the POST, but it had no effect. So I began my journal of trying to figure out WHY it had no effect in spite of all of the documentation saying it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this took a lot longer than I care to admit, so I am posting the solution here for posterity.

I increased my logging for the "Microsoft" namespace from WARN to INFO, and I noticed it was hitting the error during the anti-forgery token validation. I enabled debugging symbols for all libraries, and began to step through the code. Sure enough, didn't seem like my custom form field limit was being respected. Through some trial and error I discovered that applying custom `FormOptions` globally worked just fine though, so I know that the settings does do what I need, it's just not working when decorating just the one action.

Ages ago, I setup my ASP.NET Core application to use the `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` to universally deal with Anti-Forgery tokens so that I didn't have to worry about doing it myself. Basically enforces validating the token for all actions that are **not** accessed using the HTTP methods GET, HEAD, TRACE or OPTIONS. The two specifically this implicitly leaves it as being required for, are POST & PUT. This was not obviously related at first, but it did turn out to be a problem because the validation was being done before my action's attributes were taking effect.

By the end of it, I discovered that if I apply the `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` directly to the action as well, it seems to be suffer no ill effects for being redundant to the global attribute. But by doing so, I am able to specify the order in which they are enforced using the Order field. By decorating my action with the following, I was able to ensure that the custom form field limits are applied before the anti-forgery token validation tries to fire, while not having to touch the global `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` at all.

Hope this helps someone else save some hours of digging.

```
[RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = 3072, Order = 1), ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Order = 2)]
```